# Elliptic regularity in Sobolev spaces of negative order

Tags: analysis, reference-request, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

I am having some trouble with Sobolev spaces of negative order. More precisely I am considering the space $W^{-1,p}(\mathbb{R}^2),$ considered as 'the' dual space of $W^{1,q}(\mathbb{R}^2).$

**Question 1:** Is there a nice reference for Sobolev spaces of negative order, for $1<p<\infty.$

**Question 2:** Suppose $f\in W^{-1,p}(\mathbb{R}^2,\mathbb{C})$ is a weak solution to the inhomogeneous Cauchy-Riemann equation, i.e. $\left\langle f,\overline{\partial} g+Sg \right\rangle$ for all smooth and compactly supported $g,$ where $\overline{\partial}$ is the Cauchy-Riemann operator and $S$ is smooth. Is it then true that $f$ is itself smooth?

I know the case $S=0$ is sometimes called Weyl's Lemma.

Answer (score 2):

1). Canonical references are Adams' *Sobolev space*, and Triebel's sequence of books on *Function spaces*. Check also MacLean's *Strongly elliptic systems ...*, and Bergh and Lögström's *Interpolation spaces*.

2). This is true by elliptic regularity. You can even take $f$ to be a distribution solving the equation in the sense of distribution. If $S$ is analytic $f$ will also be analytic. Sample references would be Folland's *Introduction to PDE*, and Taylor's *PDE I*.

Comment: Another sample reference: [this thread](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/183578/elliptic-regularity-for-solutions-in-distributional-sense/183664#183664). :)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about question 2.  For 1, I would check out "Sobolev Spaces" by Robert Alexander Adams, John J. F. Fournier.